REGEX code error in Excel 365 Office Script code
I want to delete private information with excel script and ms automation.
I have trouble coding excel script without debugging tool. So I ask to help me.
What's problems?
Thank you very much.
--- There are serveral error like this.
Line 22: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
Spread syntax requires ...iterable not be null or undefined
--- All code
    `function main
    (
        workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, text: string): Array<string> {
    const thRegex = /<th[^>]*>(.*?)<\/th>/g;
    const tdRegex = /<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/g;

    const match = text.match(thRegex);
    const groups = [...match];
    const match2 = text.match(tdRegex);
    const groups2 = [...match2];

    // for (const match of matches) {
    //   console.log(match[1]);
    //   console.log(match.index)
    // }

    if (match && match2) {
        for (let key = 0; key < groups.length; key++) {
            // for (const mat of match) {
            // const mat=match[key];
            // const mat2=match2[key];
            const textTitle = groups[key][1];
            const textValue = groups2[key][1];

            if (textTitle === '총 금액' || textTitle === '금액') {
                text = text.replace(groups[key][0], '');
                text = text.replace(groups2[key][0], '');
            }

            if (textTitle === '카드번호' || textTitle === '승인번호' || textTitle === '보내는 분' ||
                textTitle === '받는 분' || textTitle === '주소' || textTitle === '등기번호') {
                text = text.replace(textValue, replaceData(textValue));
            }
        }
    }

    var strings = [text];
    return strings
    // return text;
}

function replaceData(name: string): string {
    const nameLength = name.length;
    if (nameLength === 0 || nameLength === 1) return '*';
    if (nameLength === 2) return name[0] + '*';

    const sung = name[0];
    const nameStar = '*'.repeat(nameLength - 1);

    return sung + nameStar;
}`


I want remove private information in email. Thank you.
